# Generating server code from WSDL

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, wsdl

I have a project which due to historical and complex reason requires a web service for testing.

On issue is that uses a web service which is not under our control but I do have the wsdl for that service.

The wsdl is client only so we have generated the client code but now need a stub client for the integration testing.

I had thought to generate a server from the wdsl and add log code and stub return values but have been unable to do that because its a client wdsl - at least thats what I think.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can test this without spending a lot of time and effort on development?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what language or frameworks you're using but, for example, in Eclipse you can select a new Web Services project, pick "Top down Java bean Web Service" from the dropdown and then supply a WSDL to generate the WS behind it. This would quickly give you the bare bones that you could use to stub the server response.